# Xamarin - TabbedPage navigation error (page must not have a parrent)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I'm getting the **Page must not already have a parent** exception. This happens when I try to navigate from a page to another page which is already contained within another tab. Before I load my pages in the TabbedPage itself I put them in one list called **pages**, this is obviously where the TabbedPage is getting its children from. I`m also trying to get this list to work with my navigation buttons. But whenever I try to use them I get the exception. Here is how I load the pages:

```
private int pageNavCount = 0;
private list<ContentPage> pages = nwe List<ContentPage> (0);

public MainCPage ()
{
    Create ();

    Children.Add(pages[0]);
    Children.Add(pages[1]);
    Children.Add(pages[2]);
}
```

and here is how I put a page into the list:

```
pages.Add (new ContentPage { 
    Title="Start Pagina", 
    BackgroundImage="@drawable/background.jpg", 
    Content = new StackLayout {
        Padding = 50,
        BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
        Opacity = 0.75,
        Children = {
            //The controls and stuff
        }
    }
});
```

And this is how I'm using the page list with my navigation buttons:

```
private  void NavButtonNext_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pageNavCount++;
    this.Navigation.PushAsync(pages[pageNavCount]);
}

private  void NavButtonPrev_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pageNavCount--;
    this.Navigation.PushAsync(ages[pageNavCount]);
}
```

When I try to push a button I get the "**Page must not already have a parent**" exception.
And I don't want to end up making new buttons for every single page! Can someone please tell me what I`m doing wrong here?

Comment: This might help:
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/06/01/navigation-with-xamarin-forms.aspx

Comment: Thanks but I've already looked at that page, but I want to use my page list with my navbuttons because I don't want to add them manually!

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve.  When you click the nav button, do you want to switch to another page already contained in another tab?    Or do you want to navigate within the same tab that is already selected?

Comment: I want to navigate to another page which is already contained in another tab as you can see in the code I posted. I thought this could work

Comment: Just a side note, but you should be able to drop the "@drawable/" part of your image path. That is Android-specific and will prevent your code from working on iOS and WinPhone. If you just specify the image as "background.jpg" then on Android it will look in the proper drawable folder automatically.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to navigate to a page in another tab that is already open, then you should do something like this:

```
// you will need a reference to your TabbedPage
pageNavCount--;
tabs.CurrentPage = pages[pageNavCount];
```

This [blog](http://www.patridgedev.com/2015/03/07/xamarin-forms-switching-tabbedpage-tabs-programmatically/) has a good writeup on programmatically switching tabs.

Comment: I should be able to navigate now but when I use pageNavCount it says it's out of bounds, it says that pageNavCount has the value of 3 while it starts at 0

Comment: Is that a value that is shared globally, or does each page have it's own reference?  Can you edit your question to show how that value is initialized in the page?

Comment: are you checking if you decrement below 0 or increment above the page count?  That sort of logic must be implemented manually.

Comment: Yes I have an if-statement to check if it's at it's maximum or minimum

Comment: But the main problem now is that pageNavCount mysteriously goes to 3 while I`m only using it while I press the button!

Comment: Something in your code must be doing that.  Are you triggering a button press event mulitple times?

Comment: Yep I added  navButton.Clicked += navButton.Clicked in every page. Now I added the in my button method, this solved the problem. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
this.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainCPage(pageNavCount));
```

And in the MainCPage constructor:

```
public MainCPage (int index)
{

Create ();

Children.Add(pages[0]);

Children.Add(pages[1]);

Children.Add(pages[2]);

CurrentPage = Children[i];

}
```

It's not the best architecture, but you will get the idea behind it at least.

Comment: Not very effective, why would I want to add all the pages again while they're already there? And besides that, this costs unnecessary memory. But thanks for the answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by setting the NavigationPage Parent property to null. I am using MasterDetailPage and MessagingCenter to switch navigation within the App.

```
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NavigationPage>(this, "Navigate", (pageItem) =>
        {
            pageItem.Parent = null; // solution
            Detail = pageItem;
            IsPresented = false;
        });
```